# Generating Credentials Auth Error - redirect_uri

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-assistant-sdk

I'm receiving an Authorization error when attempting to generate an authorization code:

> Error 400: invalid_request
>
> You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's
> OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure.
>
> If you’re the app developer, make sure that these request details
> comply with Google policies. redirect_uri: urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob

I've used this Google tutorial to replicate and confirm the issue:

https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/embed/install-sample?hl=en_US

It is generating this URL:

[https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=[HIDDEN]&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fassistant-sdk-prototype&state=[HIDDEN]&prompt=consent&access_type=offline](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=%5BHIDDEN%5D&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fassistant-sdk-prototype&state=%5BHIDDEN%5D&prompt=consent&access_type=offline)

Comment: Just ran into this with an expo/react native app on first successful run from the store :(

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround provided by jdtoth on Github: https://github.com/greghesp/assistant-relay/issues/266#issuecomment-1065940698

Thanks jdtoth!

---

> I found a workaround for creating a new user. In my case, I needed to
> create a specific type of API credential. Here is what I did:
>
> Create a new OAuth Client credential using the link below, ensuring
> the application type is "Web application" and set Authorized Redirect
> URIs to "http://localhost"
>
> https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials
>
> Download the key, and create the user in the Assistant Relay appas you
> tried before. When it opens a new browser window to authorize the
> google account, you might need to bypass a warning. After you do this,
> a blank browser window will open but the address bar will contain the
> auth code you need. Grab the code from the relevant part of the URL
> here and paste it back into the Assistant Relay app:
>
> http://localhost/?code=**COPYCODEFROMHERE**&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fassistant-sdk-prototype
>
> Let me know if this works. I am successfully sending commands to the
> Assistant Relay server but nothing is playing on my speakers.